# Memory test operation without pointers in NXC on NXT?

Tags: pointers, memory, assembly, nxt, nxc

I'm trying to write a memory test program for the NXT, since I have several with burned memory cells and would like to identify which NXTs are unusable. This program is intended to test each byte in memory for integrity by:

1. Allocating 64 bits to an Linear Feedback Shift Register randomizer
2. Adding another byte to a memory pointer
3. Writing random data to the selected memory cell
4. Verifying the data is read back correctly

However, I then discovered through these attempts that the NXT doesn't actually support pointer operations. Thus, I can't simply iterate the pointer byte and read its location to test.

How do I go about iterating over indexes in memory without pointers?

Comment: If you can't use pointers, then you basically haven't got C ... ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, admittedly, the language this is programmed in is called `Not eXactly C (NXC)`. Unfortunately, at an assembly level, pointers aren't supported, so this is what I've got to deal with.

Comment: The NXT supports pointers, but NXC does not (at this time). You should check out [Robot C](http://robotc.net) - it's well worth the price.

Comment: @bungeshea I'm already using RobotC for another project. I need to run a memory test - you don't have assembly level access or pointer access in RobotC.

Comment: Pointers in RobotC: http://www.robotc.net/wiki/Pointers and http://botbench.com/blog/2013/01/14/tutorial-pointers-in-robotc/

Comment: @bungshea Wow, that's new. Compiling on my version gives `Error: Pointers not supported!` Guess I'll have to update.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't really get direct memory access in either NBC/NXC or RobotC.

From what I know, both run on an NXT firmware emulator; so the bad memory address[es] might change from your program's point of view (assuming the emulator does virtual memory).

To actual run bare metal, I would suggest using the NXTBINARY function of John Hansen's modified firmware as described here:
http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/lego/nxt-native/

The enhanced fimware can be found at:
http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/test_releases/